# How to use this method (pd.DataFrame) to create three columns, instead of two?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Using this method (pd.DataFrame), I only know how to create two columns in a dataframe. This makes sense to me because, in the dictionary given as the value, the key is the first column and the value is the second column.

Is there a way I can change this method to work for three columns?

```
quantities = dict()
quotes = dict()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Defining the rows
    product_code = row["ProductCode"]
    quantity = row["Quantity"]
    customer_code = row["Customer Code"]

    # Quantities Logic
    if product_code in quantities.keys():
        quantities[product_code] += quantity
    else:
        quantities[product_code] = quantity

    # Customers Logic
    if product_code in quotes.keys():
        quotes[product_code][customer_code] = quantity
    else:
        quotes[product_code] = {customer_code: quantity}

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data=quantities.items(), columns=["Product", "Quantity"])

result_df.to_csv("ResultData.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: What do you want in the third column?

Comment: @Nick I want to add, in this case the customers, which is defined as the "quotes" dictionary. It's a 3 dimensional dictionary, so it has to be indexed [product_code].

Comment: Do you want to replicate the product/quantity for each customer? It would be helpful to have some sample input and expected output data to better understand your needs

Comment: for sure, one way to build DataFrame is dictionary but it does mean you can have only Key and Value, you can also have Key and Value as a list.So your column names can be Keys and values as a list. refer this: ` import pandas as pd
test_dictionary={'Date': ['Jan1','Feb1', 'Mar1', 'Apr1'],
    'ON': [4, 5, 7, 7],
    'QC':[1,4,6,7],
    'BC':[2,3,4,8]}
df=pd.DataFrame(test_dictionary,columns=["Date", "ON","QC","BC"])
df.head(4)`

Comment: Please include a sample of source DataFrame and the expected result, especially in the case of your 3-column result.

Answer (score 2):

For tests I took the following DataFrame:

```
  ProductCode CustomerCode  Quantity
0          P1           C1        10
1          P1           C2        20
2          P1           C1         5
3          P1           C2         7
4          P2           C1        15
5          P2           C2        12
6          P2           C1         7
7          P2           C2         4
8          P2           C1         1
```

The first remark is that your logic concerning products and customers should be
extended.

After you state that *quotes* contains a key for the current *product_code*,
you should have 2 branches:

- if second-level key for *customer_code* exists, you should add *quantity*
  there,
- otherwise you should save *quantity* under *customer_code* (second-level)
  key.

The code to do it (without the Quantities Logic) can be e.g.:

```
quotes = dict()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    product_code = row["ProductCode"]
    customer_code = row["CustomerCode"]
    quantity = row["Quantity"]
    if product_code in quotes.keys():
        qp = quotes[product_code]
        if customer_code in qp.keys():
            qp[customer_code] += quantity
        else:
            qp[customer_code] = quantity
    else:
        quotes[product_code] = {customer_code: quantity}
```

The result, for my source data, is:

```
{'P1': {'C1': 15, 'C2': 27}, 'P2': {'C1': 23, 'C2': 16}}
```

To get this result in a more *pandasonic* way:

1. Create a *Series* with a *MultiIndex* for *ProductCode* and *CustomerCode*
   and sum *Quantity* column:

   ```
   s = df.groupby(['ProductCode', 'CustomerCode']).Quantity.sum()
   ```
2. Then generate the result:

   ```
   quotes = {k: v[k].to_dict() for k, v in s.groupby(level=0)}
   ```

The result is just the same as above.

Or if you want to have a 3-column DataFrame with sums (by *ProductCode* and
*CustomerCode*), run:

```
result = df.groupby(['ProductCode', 'CustomerCode']).Quantity.sum().reset_index()
```

This time the result is:

```
  ProductCode CustomerCode  Quantity
0          P1           C1        15
1          P1           C2        27
2          P2           C1        23
3          P2           C2        16
```